# Iframe throws ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED on GZIP js file

Tags: iframe, gzip

I'm trying to show a website that uses compressed js files in an `iframe` within another React website. Accessing the site directly works but when I load it in the `iframe`, it throws the error `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`. Is iframe not capable of handling gzipped files?

```
  <iframe src="/path/to/file/on/local/server" style={styles.iframe} />
```

[image]

The response header shows Content-Encoding: gzip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: yes, iframe of Chrome supports gzip.

Longer answer is that the server was configured poorly and basically was sending a fallback html file instead of the gzipped file.